# Splash Screen that Supports Loading Progress

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef, caliburn.micro

I have the following bootstrapper class using Caliburn Micro for my MVVM framework

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private List<Assembly> priorityAssemblies;

    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        PreInitialize();
        Initialize();
    }

    protected virtual void PreInitialize() { }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"./");
        AssemblySource.Instance.AddRange(
             directoryCatalog.Parts
                  .Select(part => ReflectionModelServices.GetPartType(part).Value.Assembly)
                  .Where(assembly => !AssemblySource.Instance.Contains(assembly)));

        priorityAssemblies = SelectAssemblies().ToList();
        var priorityCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(priorityAssemblies.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)));
        var priorityProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(priorityCatalog);

        // Now get all other assemblies (excluding the priority assemblies).
        var mainCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(
            AssemblySource.Instance
                .Where(assembly => !priorityAssemblies.Contains(assembly))
                .Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)));
        var mainProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(mainCatalog);

        Container = new CompositionContainer(priorityProvider, mainProvider);
        priorityProvider.SourceProvider = Container;
        mainProvider.SourceProvider = Container;

        var batch = new CompositionBatch();

        BindServices(batch);
        batch.AddExportedValue(mainCatalog);

        Container.Compose(batch);
    }

    protected virtual void BindServices(CompositionBatch batch)
    {
        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        batch.AddExportedValue(Container);
        batch.AddExportedValue(this);
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        String contract = String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ?
            AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) :
            key;
        var exports = Container.GetExports<object>(contract);

        if (exports.Any())
            return exports.First().Value;

        throw new Exception(
            String.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValues<object>(
            AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType));
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        Container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs suea)
    {
        base.OnStartup(sender, suea);
        DisplayRootViewFor<IMainWindow>();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> SelectAssemblies()
    {
        return new[] { Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() };
    }

    protected CompositionContainer Container { get; set; }

    internal IList<Assembly> PriorityAssemblies
    {
        get { return priorityAssemblies; }
    }
}
```

This is fine, works well, loads my exported modules etc. Now I want to implement a splash screen that shows progress (a progress bar and information on the loaded exports etc.), so I don't want the standard WPF `SplashScreen` which is merely a static image.

Now I have seen [Custom caliburn.micro splashscreen with shell screen conductor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141186/custom-caliburn-micro-splashscreen-with-shell-screen-conductor) but for me this is not the awswer, it is only after `OnStartup` that the MEF exports are loaded.

So, I have added the following `SplashScreenManager` class

```
[Export(typeof(ISplashScreenManager))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class SplashScreenManager : ISplashScreenManager
{
    private IWindowManager windowManager;
    private ISplashScreen splashScreen;

    private Thread splashThread;
    private Dispatcher splashDispacher;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public SplashScreenManager(IWindowManager windowManager, ISplashScreen splashScreen)
    {
        if (windowManager == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("windowManager cannot be null");

        if (splashScreen == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("splashScreen cannot be null");

        this.windowManager = windowManager;
        this.splashScreen = splashScreen;
    }

    public void ShowSplashScreen()
    {
        splashDispacher = null;
        if (splashThread == null)
        {
            splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoShowSplashScreen));
            splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            splashThread.IsBackground = true;
            splashThread.Start();
            Log.Trace("Splash screen thread started");
        }
    }

    private void DoShowSplashScreen()
    {
        splashDispacher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
            new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(splashDispacher));

        splashScreen.Closed += (s, e) =>
            splashDispacher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            new System.Action(delegate { windowManager.ShowWindow(splashScreen); }));

        Dispatcher.Run();
        Log.Trace("Splash screen shown and dispatcher started");
    }

    public void CloseSplashScreen()
    {
        if (splashDispacher != null)
        {
            splashDispacher.BeginInvoke(
                new System.Action(delegate { splashScreen.Close(); }));
            Log.Trace("Splash screen close requested");
        }
    }

    public ISplashScreen SplashScreen
    {
        get { return splashScreen; }
    }
}
```

which attempts shows the splash screen on a background thread using Caliburn's `IWindowManager`. Where `ISplashScreenManager` is

```
public interface ISplashScreenManager
{
    void ShowSplashScreen();

    void CloseSplashScreen();

    ISplashScreen SplashScreen { get; }
}
```

and then we have the `ISplashScreen[ViewModel]` implementation

```
[Export(typeof(ISplashScreen))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class SplashScreenViewModel : Screen, ISplashScreen, ISupportProgress
{
    // Code to provide updates to the view etc. 
}
```

with `ISplashScreen` as an empty marker interface at this point.

*So my question is how do I correctly order the invocation of the `SplashScreenViewModel` so that the splash screen gets displayed whilst the modules get loaded in the bootstrapper `GetInstance` method?*

I have tried doing something like

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs suea)
{
    var splashManager = Container.GetExportedValue<ISplashScreenManager>();
    var windowManager = IoC.Get<IWindowManager>();
    windowManager.ShowWindow(splashManager.SplashScreen);

    base.OnStartup(sender, suea);
    DisplayRootViewFor<IMainWindow>();

    splashManager.SplashScreen.TryClose();
}
```

But this instantly closes the splash screen and does not make use of my multi-threaded code to show the splash screen in the `SplashScreenManager`.

I am open to amending the code heavily to do what I want, but I can seem to get the correct  combination at this point. I want to avoid going too deep into threading and using `ManualResetEvent`s, before asking you fine folk for advice on how best to proceed.

Thanks for your time.

---

Partial Solution: I now have the following code in the `OnStartup` method in my bootstrapper class

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs suea)
{
    splashScreenManager = Container.GetExportedValue<ISplashScreenManager>();
    splashScreenManager.ShowSplashScreen();

    Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
    Application.Current.MainWindow = null;

    base.OnStartup(sender, suea);
    DisplayRootViewFor<IMainWindow>();

    // I have also tried this.
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => DisplayRootViewFor<IMainWindow>());

    splashScreenManager.CloseSplashScreen();
}
```

The `SplashScreenManager` class is

```
[Export(typeof(ISplashScreenManager))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class SplashScreenManager : ISplashScreenManager
{
    private IWindowManager windowManager;
    private ISplashScreenViewModel splashScreen;

    private Thread splashThread;
    private Dispatcher splashDispacher;

    public void ShowSplashScreen()
    {
        splashDispacher = null;
        if (splashThread == null)
        {
            splashThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoShowSplashScreen));
            splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            splashThread.IsBackground = true;
            splashThread.Name = "SplashThread"; 
            splashThread.Start();
            Log.Trace("Splash screen thread started");
        }
    }

    private void DoShowSplashScreen()
    {
        // Get the splash vm on the splashThread.
        splashScreen = IoC.Get<ISplashScreenViewModel>();

        splashDispacher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
            new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(splashDispacher));

        splashScreen.Closed += (s, e) =>
            splashDispacher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
        splashScreen.Show();

        Dispatcher.Run();
        Log.Trace("Splash screen shown and dispatcher started");
    }

    public void CloseSplashScreen()
    {
        if (splashDispacher != null)
        {
            splashScreen.Close();
            Log.Trace("Splash screen close requested");
        }
    }

    public ISplashScreenViewModel SplashScreen
    {
        get { return splashScreen; }
    }
}
```

This now displays the splash screen with a indeterminate progress bar (not yet wired up the messages) which looks like

Now, the problem is, when we hit the line

```
DisplayRootViewFor<IMainWindow>();
```

it throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the message

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

The stack trace is

> at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValue(DependencyProperty dp)
>      at MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow.get_Flyouts() in d:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\src\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro.Shared\Controls\MetroWindow.cs:line 269
>      at MahApps.Metro.Controls.MetroWindow.ThemeManagerOnIsThemeChanged(Object sender, OnThemeChangedEventArgs e) in d:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\src\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro.Shared\Controls\MetroWindow.cs:line 962
>      at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
>      at MahApps.Metro.Controls.SafeRaise.Raise[T](EventHandler`1 eventToRaise, Object sender, T args) in d:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\src\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro.Shared\Controls\SafeRaise.cs:line 26
>      at MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.OnThemeChanged(Accent newAccent, AppTheme newTheme) in d:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\src\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro.Shared\ThemeManager\ThemeManager.cs:line 591
>      at MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(ResourceDictionary resources, Tuple`2 oldThemeInfo, Accent newAccent, AppTheme newTheme) in d:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\src\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro.Shared\ThemeManager\ThemeManager.cs:line 407
>      at MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application app, Accent newAccent, AppTheme newTheme) in d:\projects\git\MahApps.Metro\src\MahApps.Metro\MahApps.Metro.Shared\ThemeManager\ThemeManager.cs:line 345
>      at Augur.Core.Themes.ThemeManager.SetCurrentTheme(String name) in F:\Camus\Augur\Src\Augur\Core\Themes\ThemeManager.cs:line 46
>      at Augur.Modules.Shell.ViewModels.ShellViewModel.OnViewLoaded(Object view) in F:\Camus\Augur\Src\Augur\Modules\Shell\ViewModels\ShellViewModel.cs:line 73
>      at Caliburn.Micro.XamlPlatformProvider.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0(Object s, RoutedEventArgs e)
>      at Caliburn.Micro.View.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(Object s, RoutedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
>      at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root)
>      at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork()
>      at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks()
>      at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
>      at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
>      at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
>      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize()
>      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)

I have attempted to change the code to use the Application dispatcher and to store the task scheduler and use that with a `Task` to get back on the Gui thread. I am not sure why I am loosing the thread context, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

The attempts to fix

```
splashScreenManager = Container.GetExportedValue<ISplashScreenManager>();
splashScreenManager.ShowSplashScreen();

Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
Application.Current.MainWindow = null;

base.OnStartup(sender, suea);
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => DisplayRootViewFor<IMainWindow>()); // Still throws the same exception.
```

or

```
splashScreenManager = Container.GetExportedValue<ISplashScreenManager>();
splashScreenManager.ShowSplashScreen();

Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
Application.Current.MainWindow = null;

base.OnStartup(sender, suea);
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    new System.Action(delegate { DisplayRootViewFor<IMainWindow>(); })); // Still throws the same exception.
```

and

```
TaskScheduler guiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

splashScreenManager = Container.GetExportedValue<ISplashScreenManager>();
splashScreenManager.ShowSplashScreen();

Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
Application.Current.MainWindow = null;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    base.OnStartup(sender, suea);
    DisplayRootViewFor<IMainWindow>();
}, CancellationToken.None, 
   TaskCreationOptions.None, 
   guiScheduler);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why the close vote. This question is well defined, shows what the issues is, shows what I have tried and also what I have researched. SMH.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just show the a splash screen window on a background thread the first thing you do in your `OnStartup` method and then close it once the initialization is finished?:

```
protected override async void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs suea)
{
    Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
    Window splashScreenWindow = null;
    Thread splashScreenWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));
        splashScreenWindow = new Window();
        splashScreenWindow.Content = new ProgressBar() { IsIndeterminate = true };
        splashScreenWindow.Closed += (ss, es) => Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
        splashScreenWindow.Show();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    }));
    splashScreenWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    splashScreenWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
    splashScreenWindowThread.Start();

    base.OnStartup(sender, suea);
    //...
    splashScreenWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => splashScreenWindow.Close()));
}
```

Comment: I like this, however, it seems as though this method exits before the `GetInstance` complete all of its work. A handful of modules are loaded _after_ this method exits. Despite this, I would also like to use a manager to allow me to swap the splash screen: reason, the bootstrapper is in an DLL assembly which is references by the executable application. This project is my "desktop framework". So another project (.exe) could reference this DLL and export a different `ISplashScreen` and it would just work - show the splash screen whilst the modules are loaded.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. This has given me a different avenue to explore. Another aspect I don't quite like with the above is that I a merely calling the `Window` directly and not strictly using MVVM - I am not one of those MVVM maniacs, but I would be nice to allow `ISpreadSheet` to me ammended via MVVM.

Comment: The OnStartup method belongs to the view and has nothing to do with MVVM. Displaying a slashscreen is the responisibility of the application itself. You could easily set the DataContext of the splash window to a view model if you want to perform some logic.

Comment: Oh, okay, I see. Are you saying that the approach of getting an `ISplashScreen` using `IoC.Get` and using the `IWindowManager` to `Show(SplashScreenViewModel)` is the wrong approach in the method, or can this approach work? I would ideally like to have a global `ISplashScreen` in bootstrapper class and instantiate in the `OnStartup` then provide progress reports from the `GetInstance` method. Have you any thought on this?

Comment: Happy to award a little bounty if you can provide further insight into the correct approach.

Comment: Why I am saying is that there is no reason to overcomplicate simple things. A splash screen is just shown initially while the application is initializing and that's why I suggested to simply pop up a window in a dedicated thread and then close it once the application has been initialized. What else do you want from a splash screen?

Comment: I want to show an accurate progress bar with info in a `TextBlock` on which modules are being loaded. As the application grows large (which it will), [from experience] this loading of MEF exports can take upto 6 seconds (depending on hardware). Also, I would like to allow the consuming application to provide the splash screen (via MEF export) & then the bootstrapper picks this up and displays it in the `OnStarup` method. I am sure what you have done above works, but I would like to try and use a splash screen manager as outlined above with `ISplashScreen` view model to allow progress support.

Comment: I think a simpler way to achieve what your after is to make the progress bar indeterminate and then show the assemblies being loaded on your splash screen. Use the  AssemblyLoad event from AppDomain.CurrentDomain to print the names on your splash screen.